# Error compiling Libxml2 in codeblocks on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, undefined, libxml2

I am in the process of porting my windows console application to Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). I am using the GNU GCC compiler to compile my application. However I can't seem to get rid of some errors, this code does function in windows with libxml2 but can't compile here.

In my build options I have included to search the path usr/include/libxml2. When I compile i still recieve the error:

```
    Datadictionary.c|| undefined reference to `xmlCheckVersion'|
    Datadictionary.c|| undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'|
    Datadictionary.c|| undefined reference to `xmlGetProp'|    
    Datadictionary.c|| undefined reference to `xmlReadFile'|
```

Now i have looked anywhere but could not find a solution.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install

`sudo apt-get install libxml2`
`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`
`sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev`
`sudo apt-get install xml-core`

Then you need to set compliler option -**I/usr/include/libxml2**
and linker option **-lxml2 -lm**

And use `# include<libxml/parser.h> instead #include "libxml/parser.h"`

Also you need to clear all previous search path settings

Comment: please, can you explain how? 'make -l/usr(include...' ? or './configure/usr(include...'? etc thanks